# How Send message from fragment to activity and received and use in activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, message

Please please don't minus my question i confused when googling.
I used [Android Tab Layout with Swipeable Views](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) in my code for when user pressed setting button on an activity.

now I  need send message from TopRatedFragment.java that extends from fragment to the activity that call the mainActivity of "Android Tab Layout with Swipeable Views".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's the solution:**

**Step 1** : From your fragment.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("key", "Your value1");
        i.putExtra("key2", "Your value2");
        i.putExtra("key3", "Your value3");
        getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

**Step 2** : In your Activity where you want the result

```
Intent getResults = getIntent();
        String firstValue = getResults.getStringExtra("key1");
        String secondValue = getResults.getStringExtra("key2");
        String thirdValue = getResults.getStringExtra("key3");
```

Use those values your needs are.

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by implementing a call back

create an interface first

```
public interface CommunicationInterface {

public void onSuccess();

public void onFailed();

}
```

then in your activity implement the interface

```
public class YourActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements  CommunicationInterface {

 //default functions
@Override
public void onSuccess() {

  //stuff you want to do in the acivity

}

@Override
public void onFailed() {
   //stuff you want to do in the acivity
}

}
```

Now in the fragment

```
public class yourfragment extends Fragment {

 CommunicationInterface callback;

 //stuffs that usually come in yor fragment and like OncreateView etc

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle outState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(outState);

   //after all the stuff you want to do in your fragment then implement      //call back function to communicate with the activity
   callback= (CommunicationInterface) getActivity();

    callback.onSuccess();//according to your purpose use where ever you like

    callback.onFailed();//according to your purpose use where ever you like

}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
  callback= (CommunicationInterface) activity;
}
}
```

Comment: This assumes that `getActivity` can always be called. There seem to be cases where that function returns `null`.

Comment: @Christian in that case initialize the call back on onAttach() method ,it gives you an context of the activity .

Answer (score 4):

Take a close look on this reference:
[Creating event callbacks to the activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks)

Answer (score 1):

The android docs recommend using this pattern of having the parent activity implement an interface of the fragment (Basically calling methods on it)

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    interface Listener {
        public void onSomeEvent();
    }

    private void somethingHappeninInTheFragment() {
        // let the activity know
        ((Listener) getActivity()).onSomeEVent();
    }
}

class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyFragment.Listener {
    // etc
    @Override
    public void onSomeEvent() {
        // handle the message from the fragment
    }
}
```

Explained with a more concrete example here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks